# Calculate elevation angle between two lat/long/alt points using cesiumjs

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Using cesiumjs, I'd like to calculate the elevation angle between two points as though we were standing on a hot air balloon at the first point. The points are simple cartographic points (lat, long, altitude).

This picture sums it up nicely
[image]

After some researching, this was a suggested approach:

> To transform your target point in the Earth-fixed frame to this local
>   horizontal plane, you can use Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame. 
>   That returns a Matrix4, which you then multiply your target point
>   vector by, yielding a new vector.  Normalize that vector, and then the
>   elevation angle is simply asin(z) of the normalized vector.

This is the code I've put together, but it returns NaN for the multiplication. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var Cesium = require('cesium');

var startPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107, 30, 3000);
var endPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-112, 25, 1000000);

//To transform your target point in the Earth-fixed frame to this local horizontal plane, you can use Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame.
var effTarget = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(endPoint)
console.log("Earth-fixed frame (target): " + effTarget);

//That returns a Matrix4, which you then multiply your target point vector by, yielding a new vector.
var multiplicationResult = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyComponents(effTarget, endPoint, multiplicationResult)
console.log("Multiplication result: " + multiplicationResult)

//Normalize that vector
var normalizationResult = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(multiplicationResult, normalizationResult);
console.log("Normalize result: " + normalizationResult)

//and then the elevation angle is simply asin(z) of the normalized vector.
var elevationAngle = Math.asin(normalizationResult.z)
console.log("Elevation angle: " + elevationAngle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Rachel Hwang's answer](https://community.cesium.com/t/calculate-elevation-angle-between-two-points/5629/6):

```js
var startPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107, 30, 3000);
var endPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-112, 25, 1000000);

// Obtain vector by taking difference of the end points.
var difference = Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(endPoint, startPoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
difference = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(difference, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
console.log("Difference: " + difference);

// Obtain surface normal by normalizing the starting point position.
var surfaceNormal = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(startPoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
console.log("Surface normal: " + surfaceNormal);

// Take the dot product of your given vector and the surface normal.
var dotProduct = Cesium.Cartesian3.dot(difference, surfaceNormal);
console.log("Dot product: " + dotProduct);

// Arcos the result.
var angle = 90 - Cesium.Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(dotProduct));
console.log("Angle: " + angle);
```

Console:

```
Difference: (-0.696260739885982, -0.7156821634654381, -0.05495473583645852)
Surface normal: (-0.2536245226271608, -0.8295684339468393, 0.4974844871160639)
Dot product: 0.7429570007551259
Angle: 47.9839196010689
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong object for your multiplication. Try using the [.multiplyByPoint](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Matrix4.html#.multiplyByPoint) method to get your new Cartesian3 result:

```
//That returns a Matrix4, which you then multiply your target point vector by, yielding a new vector.
var multiplicationResult = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(effTarget, endPoint, multiplicationResult)
console.log("Multiplication result: " + multiplicationResult)
```

You should be able to continue with that `multiplicationResult`.

Answer (score 0):

This is heading in the right direction, but isn't quite right yet:

```
var startPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107, 30, 3000);
var endPoint = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-112, 25, 1000000);

//To transform your target point in the Earth-fixed frame to this local horizontal plane, you can use Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame.
var effTarget = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(endPoint);
console.log("Earth-fixed frame (target): " + effTarget);

//That returns a Matrix4, which you then multiply your target point vector by, yielding a new vector.
var multiplicationResult = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(effTarget, startPoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
console.log("Multiplication result: " + multiplicationResult);

//Normalize that vector
var normalizationResult = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(multiplicationResult, normalizationResult);
console.log("Normalize result: " + normalizationResult);

//and then the elevation angle is simply asin(z) of the normalized vector.
var elevationAngle = Math.asin(normalizationResult.z);
console.log("Elevation angle: " + Cesium.Math.toDegrees(elevationAngle));
```

Comment: Did you try the answer I provided?

Comment: Hi eth, yes but unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though